# Delphi - Interface inheritance with generics

Tags: delphi, generics, inheritance, delphi-xe2

I am currently stuck with a compiling error, no one in our company can help and I am sadly not finding the correct search patterns for SO or google.

As code I am using 2 Interfaces, inherited and 2 Classes, inherited.
The following code reproduces the error:

```
program Project22;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
type
  IStorageObject = interface(IInterface)
  end;
  TObjectStorage<T: IStorageObject> = class(TObject)
  end;
  IKeyStorageObject<TKey> = interface(IStorageObject)
  end;
  TKeyObjectStorage<TKey, T: IKeyStorageObject<TKey>> = class(TObjectStorage<T>)
  end;
  TImplementingClass<TKey> = class(TInterfacedObject, IKeyStorageObject<TKey>)
  end;
begin
  TKeyObjectStorage<Integer, TImplementingClass<Integer>>.Create;
end.
```

The compiler error for 'TKeyObjectStorage' is:

> [DCC Error] Project22.dpr(11): E2514 Type parameter 'T' must support interface 'IStorageObject'

What I think is, that the compiler is not recognizing that Parameter T of the Class 'TKeyObjectStorage' correctly. 
It should be correct, since the wanted Type 'IKeyStorageObject' has the parent type IStorageObject.

Why is this not working? What am I doing wrong? Is this not possible in Delphi?

Comment: Did you just completely change the question?!! Did you just replace that comma with as semi-colon?!! And the code you posted is still not enough to exhibit the error. Please do what I suggested and post a **complete program**. I showed you how in my answer.

Comment: Sorry for this David, Yes i did, but the ',' did not throw an or this error and was only a minor oversight. Sry again.

Comment: @Hugie, Do not change the question to deviate from it's original problem.  Any errors that are in the original need to stay in the question; however create a console app with the minimal code to demonstrate the issue. and paste **that** console app in the question.

Comment: OK, I think I have a workaround for you. Code at the top of my answer compiles in XE2. I also should have been more careful in my compiler selection.

Comment: I've put in the SSCCE, with the original `,` error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**

The original question had a problem which I identified (see below). However, the fix I describe there is fine for XE3 and later, but that program below does not compile in XE2. Thus I conclude that this is an XE2 generics compiler bug.

Anyway, here's a workaround for **Delphi XE2**:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
type
  IStorageObject = interface(IInterface)
  end;
  TObjectStorage<T: IStorageObject> = class(TObject)
  end;
  IKeyStorageObject<TKey> = interface(IStorageObject)
  end;
  TKeyObjectStorage<TKey; T: IKeyStorageObject<TKey>, IStorageObject> = class(TObjectStorage<T>)
  end;
  TImplementingClass<TKey> = class(TInterfacedObject, IStorageObject, IKeyStorageObject<TKey>)
  end;
begin
  TKeyObjectStorage<Integer, TImplementingClass<Integer>>.Create;
end.
```

---

**Original answer**

It would have been better if you had provided a complete program that exhibited the compiler error. You need to attempt to instantiate an object to see that error.

But, I think I've reproduced your problem. So I believe that the issue is that this code:

```
TKeyObjectStorage<TKey, T: IKeyStorageObject<TKey>> = ...
```

applies the generic constraint to both `TKey` and `T`. Now, clearly you only want the constraint to apply to `T` so you'll need to write:

```
TKeyObjectStorage<TKey; T: IKeyStorageObject<TKey>> = ...
```

Here's a short program that compiles following the change in **Delphi XE3**:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
type
  IStorageObject = interface(IInterface)
  end;
  TObjectStorage<T: IStorageObject> = class(TObject)
  end;
  IKeyStorageObject<TKey> = interface(IStorageObject)
  end;
  TKeyObjectStorage<TKey; T: IKeyStorageObject<TKey>> = class(TObjectStorage<T>)
  end;
  TImplementingClass<TKey> = class(TInterfacedObject, IKeyStorageObject<TKey>)
  end;
begin
  TKeyObjectStorage<Integer, TImplementingClass<Integer>>.Create;
end.
```

This is quite a nuance, the changing of a comma to a semi-colon. Programming by significant punctuation is never much fun. That said, you are familiar with the difference between commas and semi-colons in formal parameter lists and so it should not come as too much of a surprise to see the same distinction drawn here.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Constraints_in_Generics#Multiple_Type_Parameters) does cover this mind you:

> **Multiple Type Parameters**
>
> When you specify constraints, you separate multiple type parameters by
>   semicolons, as you do with a parameter list declaration:
>
> ```
> type
>   TFoo<T: ISerializable; V: IComparable>
> ```
>
> Like parameter declarations, multiple type parameters can be grouped
>   together in a comma list to bind to the same constraints:
>
> ```
> type
>   TFoo<S, U: ISerializable> ...
> ```
>
> In the example above, `S` and `U` are both bound to the `ISerializable`
>   constraint.

Comment: Thx David, i edited my code to a complete unit (without instantiation) and it reproduces the error in a clean project.
And yes, you were right, i had a minor logical mistake due to ,->; but it was not the error i am dealing with. Thx for your effort.

Comment: Your update does not produce an error. Try it. Start with a new project, and add that unit, and then compile. Guess what, it compiles. As I said in my answer, you need to instantiate an object. I'm a bit frustrated by this. You need to learn how to make an SSCCE so that you don't waste our time. I'm off to lunch now. I hope the question is fixed by the time I return.

Comment: I've copy-pasted your code into XE2, it still gives an error: `[DCC Error] Project22.dpr(11): E2514 Type parameter 'T' must support interface 'IStorageObject'` on this line: `TKeyObjectStorage<TKey; T: IKeyStorageObject<TKey>> = class(TObjectStorage<T>)`

Comment: @Johan Gah, XE2 compiler bug fixed in XE3. Guess what compiler I am using.

Comment: @David. It's my first Question and i am Sorry for waisting your time.

Comment: @David, so this is a Compiler Bug in XE2? It is an XE2 related Question. Then this is the answer i am searching for.

Comment: @Hugie It's a pretty good question. It's almost perfect. You just should have made a complete program. You were 99% of the way there. But I got it wrong too by using the wrong compiler, so hey, if I'm not perfect, why am I giving you such a hard time?!!

Comment: @David Because i need to learn not to edit the Question too much :D