# How do I implement a generic class that has an constraint for a generic interface?

Tags: delphi, generics, interface

I have an Interface

```
IMyInterface<T>
```

and a class

```
TMyClass<T>
```

and now I want that I can only pass classes to TMyClass as a type, that also implement IMyInterface.

First I tried

```
TMyClass<T:IMyInterface<T>>
```

but as expected, now the compiler wants me to give him a type which implements an interface with the type of class itself that implements the interface

Second try was

```
TMyClass<D,T:IMyInterface<D>>
```

where I thought, D would then be the shared DataType, both TMyInterface and TMyClass would use.

So after declaring the class implementing the interface

```
TMyIntegerClass = class(TInterfacedObject,IMyInterface<Integer>)
```

The declaration

```
GMyClass:TMyClass<Integer,TMyIntegerClass>
```

failed with compiler error:

```
E2514 Type parameter 'D' must support interface 'IMyInterface<System.Integer>'
```

Any pointers?

Comment: What about using a semicolon instead of a comma: `TMyClass<D; T: IMyInterface<D>>`, analogue to parameters of a function?

Comment: That makes no difference. Syntax at this point still okay, but same compiler error in the declaration of the variable.

Comment: oh yes, it most definitely makes a difference. See my answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682057/delphi-interface-inheritance-with-generics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This compiles in Delphi 10.2.2 Tokyo:

```
type
  IMyInterface<T> = interface
  ['{F810B6BC-78F7-4026-BA83-70435150B758}']
  end;

  TMyClass<D; T: IMyInterface<D>> = class // note the semicolon!
  end;

  TMyIntegerClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyInterface<Integer>)
  end;

var
  GMyClass: TMyClass<Integer, TMyIntegerClass>;
```

If, *in the declaration of the class*, I use `<D, T: TSomeType>` (comma!) then both `D` and `T` **are declared to be of the same type**, like parameters of a function:

```
procedure Blah(D, T: TSomeType);
```

*Parameters `D` and `T` are of the same type, i.e. `TSomeType`*.

Now, if you pass an `Integer` for `D`, you get an error, similar to the one you got. The compiler expects two `TSomeType` parameters.

But if I use `<D; T: TSomeType>` then `D` and `T` are **separate types**, i.e. `D` is of an unknown type and `T` is of type `TSomeType`. So now, `D` is **not** declared as `TSomeType` and there is no error if you pass `Integer`.

Oh, and [this is documented too](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Constraints_in_Generics#Multiple_Type_Parameters).

Comment: Yep, sorry it actually works, tried it on wrong class... set to accepted answer :)